# Java XNOR operator

Tags: java

I do some research and I wrote some simple programs in java that suits my needs. I used logical operators AND,OR,XOR on integers but I miss XNOR operator. That what I'm looking for is a XNOR operator that behaves just same as others mentioned (could be applied on integers). Is it possible from somebody to write such a class in Java?

Answer (score 85):

```
boolean xnor(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return !(a ^ b);
}
```

or even simpler:

```
boolean xnor(boolean a, boolean b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

If you are actually talking about **bitwise** operators (you say you're operating on `int`), then you will need a variant of the first snippet:

```
int xnor(int a, int b) {
    return ~(a ^ b);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer with int xnor(int a, int b) {
    return ~(a ^ b);
}
but it gives false results .For instance 10 NXOR 12 = 9 it is not negative number.

Comment: @user1092472: For a 32-bit type, it is.

Comment: @user1092472: If you only want to perform the operation on a subset of the bits, you will need to perform a mask with `&`.

Comment: For XOR or XNOR on two boolean values, can't you just do `if (b1 != b2) //XOR` or `if (b1 == b2) //XNOR`? What advantage does doing `if (b1 ^ b2) //XOR` or `if (!(b1 ^ b2)) //XNOR` give?

Comment: XNOR = inverse of XOR

Answer (score 25):

The logical XNOR operator is `==`.

Do you mean *bitwise*?

Comment: Here is my little program with xor operator. I need the same program with XNOR operator. `code` public class xor
{

public static void main (String argv[])
{

int i=1;

for (int j=0;j<100;j++){
int x = ((i) ^ (j));
System.out.print(j);
System.out.print(" ");
System.out.println(x);
} `code`

Answer (score 4):

The operator for `XNOR` is `A==B`, or `!(A^B)`.
This returns a `boolean` value.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!a ^ b) doSomething();
```

It gives the same result so you do not have to use brackets.

And I would prefer an XOR gate more since a mistake is likely to be made if you accidentally use a `=` at somewhere which supposed to be a `==`.

```
if (a = b) doSomething(); // performs like "if (b) doSomething();"
```

A bitwise version as well.

```
someInt = ~a ^ b
```

Comment: the bitwise xnor formula which you gave is not working.